# Ruby on Rails, change source of image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, file

I have a JavaScript function which changes one of the images on my web page when the user scrolls down

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
      switchToStatic();
    }
    else {
      switchToAnimated();
    }
}

function switchToAnimated() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $('body').css('padding-top', '0');
        $('#logo').attr('src', '../assets/blue_logo.png')
        $('#logo').css('width', '15vw');
        $('.navbar').css("background-color", 'transparent');
    }
}

function switchToStatic() {
    $('body').css('padding-top', '50px');
    $('#logo').attr('src', '../assets/white_logo.png')
    $('#logo').css('width', '7.5vw');
    $('.navbar').css("background-color", '#3B98F2');
}
```

My application is built on Ruby on Rails. The slim markup looks like this

```
a href="http://www.thisisarealsite.com" 
    = image_tag("white_logo.png", alt: "logo", id: "logo")
```

On my localhost the functions work properly but when we launch the site to production the files are missing. I know rails sucks everything into a common directory but I don't know how to fix this to get the image to behave the way I want it to on both localhost and production. I tried taking away the '../assets/' reference and just pointing to the file but that did not work on either localhost or production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is using asset pipeline which adds fingerprints to each js, css and other assets file. So you cannot just fetch file by its name, you need to use the name with fingerprint. `image_tag` helper will generate correct paths on production, so what you need to do is to somehow inject those paths into javascript.

For example you can do something like this:

```
javascript:
  var blueLogoPath = "#{asset_path('blue_logo.png')}";
  var whiteLogoPath = "#{asset_path('white_logo.png')}";
```

And then

```
$('#logo').attr('src', whiteLogoPath);
```

Comment: I like this answer, the problem is the browser renders it to plain HTML with double quotes which end up mismatching and throwing a syntax error.

Comment: Actually strike that, I got it to render by switching the double quotes with single quotes. Unfortuately, now the src is set to an image tag. I need to use a different method besides attr

Comment: Hey @NickGilbert I updated my answer. You need to call `asset_path` helper instead of `image_tag`. It will generate plain url.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your logos to your `public` folder and referencing them like this:

`$('#logo').attr('src', '/blue_logo.png')`

`$('#logo').attr('src', '/white_logo.png')`

Comment: /blue_logo.png is not found on localhost

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! Forgot to mention you should move your logos to the public folder. I've just updated my answer for clarity.