# Ruby on Rails - Change logo image on page scroll not activating

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

**Ruby 2.3.1**

**Rails 5.1.2**

I am trying to change the logo image to another one in my navbar when I start scrolling but no success so far. In regular HTML, it worked fine by having it this way:

```
<div class="logo">
  <a class="logo-wrap" href="index.html">
    <img class="logo-img logo-img-main" src="img/logo/ymk_logo_lw.png" alt="Ymk Logo">
    <img class="logo-img logo-img-active" src="img/logo/ymk_logo.png" alt="Ymk Logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

And having the following CSS properties:

```
.header .logo-img-main {
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}

.header .logo-img-active {
  display: none;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}

.header .logo .logo-img-main {
  display: none;
}
  .header .logo .logo-img-active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.page-on-scroll .header .logo-img-main {
  display: none;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}
.page-on-scroll .header .logo-img-active {
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}
```

And JS:

```
var Layout = function () {
    'use strict';

    // handle on page scroll
    var handleHeaderOnScroll = function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
            // var colorLogoPath = "#{asset_path('logo/ymk_logo.png')}";
            $('body').addClass('page-on-scroll');
            // $('.logo-img .logo-img-active').attr('src', colorLogoPath);
        } else {
            // var whiteLogoPath = "#{asset_path('logo/ymk_logo_lw.png')}";
            $('body').removeClass('page-on-scroll');
            // $('.logo-img .logo-img-main').attr('src', whiteLogoPath);
        }
    }

return {
        init: function () {
            handleHeaderOnScroll(); // initial setup for fixed header

            // handle minimized header on page scroll
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                handleHeaderOnScroll();
            });
        }
    };
}();

$(document).ready(function() {
    Layout.init();
});
```

On the JS section, I commented out some part since I was trying to implement some of the code from this **[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496591/ruby-on-rails-change-source-of-image-with-javascript)** but could only get to some point since it was showing me the images.

So I went back and decided to implement and `if` statement into the html:

```
        <div class="logo">
          <a class="logo-wrap">
           <% if image_tag("logo/ymk_logo_lw.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-main", :alt => "Ymk Logo White") %>
            <%= image_tag("logo/ymk_logo_lw.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-main", :alt => "Ymk Logo White") %>
           <% else %>
            <%= image_tag("logo/ymk_logo.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-active", :alt => "Ymk Logo OG") %>
           <% end %>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Now here, when I load the page the first logo that should appear, `ymk_logo_lw.png`, does not show but when I start scrolling, the second logo appears `ymk_logo.png`.

Would appreciate any suggestion, I am pretty new to Ruby and I am just getting the grab of it. Thanks!

**`application.js` requirements:**

```
//= require jquery-3.2.1.min.js
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require swiper/js/swiper.jquery.min.js
//= require components/swiper.min.js
//= require jquery.easing.js
//= require jquery.back-to-top.js
//= require jquery.smooth-scroll.js
//= require jquery.wow.min.js
//= require jquery.parallax.min.js
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry.pkgd.min.js
//= require masonry/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js
//= require components/wow.min.js
//= require components/masonry.min.js
//= require components/gmap.min.js
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**`_navbar.html.erb:**

```
    <header class="header navbar-fixed-top">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="menu-container">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="toggle-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo">
              <a class="logo-wrap" href="/">
                <%= image_tag("logo/ymk_logo_lw.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-main", :alt => "Ymk Logo White") %>
                <%= image_tag("logo/ymk_logo.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-active", :alt => "Ymk Logo OG") %>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- End Logo -->
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-collapse">
            <div class="menu-container">
              <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-item-child nav-item-hover #{yield(:root_active)}", :"data-no-turbolink" => true, method: "get" %>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "nav-item-child nav-item-hover #{yield(:about_active)}", :"data-no-turbolink" => true, method: "get" %>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: "nav-item-child nav-item-hover #{yield(:contact_active)}", :"data-no-turbolink" => true, method: "get" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Navbar Collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- Navbar -->
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the ERB solution there. The ERB templates are parsed and generated on server side and then sent to browser, so your if/else clause will be evaluated on server and the result will go to browser, you end up having one image tag. Once the view is rendered, you cannot alter it by server side code. So the logic you have made in your view with Ruby is not correct.

Change your code like this:

html:

```
<div class='header'>
  <div class="logo">
    <a class="logo-wrap" href="index.html">
      <%= image_tag("logo/ymk_logo_lw.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-main", :alt => "Ymk Logo White") %>
      <%= image_tag("logo/ymk_logo.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-active", :alt => "Ymk Logo White") %>
    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

- The logo div should be subclass of header. If it's already like that, remove it (loading from partial maybe?)
- Notice the `<%=` (equal sign). When you want to print the expression on screen (you're not doing this currently on your own code).

CSS:

```
.header .logo-img-main {
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}

.header .logo-img-active {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}

.page-on-scroll .header .logo-img-main {
  display: none !important;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}

.page-on-scroll .header .logo-img-active {
  display: inline-block !important;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}
```

- you had multiple definition of the same classes causing it to override each other.
- I updated the `.header .logo-img-active` with `position: fixed` so the logo would be visible when scrolling.

JS:

There is nothing wrong with the JS file. Just make sure you have the `jquery-rails` in your `Gemfile` and you have required it in `application.js` like `//= require jquery`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! So what are the alternatives on making it happen. The other answer provides an update on my commented out javascript but it is still showing me one image.

Comment: @wlmrlsda Updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Now both images are showing. The first logo it shows in the position that it should show and the other logo, when I start scrolling down, is moved to the right bottom corner of the first logo, a little bigger in size and outside of the navbar. As for the `jquery-rails`, is it necessary since I already have downloaded the jquery files? Check out the bottom part of my question. I added my requirements.

Comment: By the way I also updated my question with my complete `_navbar.html.erb`

Comment: @wlmrlsdaYou most likely have a problem in your css and another part of your code is overwriting these. You should check the browser console and check which part is causing it. I have already made a test Rails app with the codes I shared and it works fine.

Comment: Issue was solved removing the `link_to` on the `erb` tags just how you showed on your answer. Left the CSS and JS as I had them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to update the src of the same image tag each time. Check the Javascript below to see how I updated the code.

```
<div class="logo">
  <a class="logo-wrap">
    <%= link_to(image_tag("logo/ymk_logo_lw.png", :class => "logo-img logo-img-main", :alt => "Ymk Logo White"), root_path) %>
   </a>
</div>
```

Javascript (Cleaned it up a bit)

```
var handleHeaderOnScroll = function() {
    var imagePath = ""
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
        imagePath = "#{asset_path('logo/ymk_logo.png')}";
        $('body').addClass('page-on-scroll');
    } else {
        imagePath = "#{asset_path('logo/ymk_logo_lw.png')}";
        $('body').removeClass('page-on-scroll');
    }
    $('.logo-img .logo-img-main').attr('src', imagePath);
}
```

Editing your CSS to be minimal

```
.header .logo-img-main {
  display: none;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}

.page-on-scroll .header .logo-img-main {
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 1, 0.7, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now the paper has changed and its showing the first logo and not the second.

Comment: Can you verify that both conditionals are being reached?

Comment: Yes they are being reached. I added `console.log(imagePath);` on both and it shows that `#{asset_path('logo/ymk_logo_lw.png')}` is showing when the scroller is on the top and `#{asset_path('logo/ymk_logo.png')}` when I start scrolling.

Comment: Try the updated CSS. I just edited it in hopes it will fix you issue. The CSS is the culprit at this point.

Comment: With the updated CSS you sent me, none of them shows up. It only shows the `ymk_logo_lw` for a brief second when I start scrolling down before my sticky navbar change from transparent to white.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle so we can modify it together? I want to get this solved for you.

Comment: Good idea, but is there a way to use the embedded ruby part in the html section in jsfiddle?

Comment: Nope, so you will have to abstract your code to be in HTML, kind of how you explained it at the top of your question.